haskell-language-server error: ghcide failed to load packages
The project is built with stack. HLS works well on the tests after running stack build. But if I run stack build --test, hls fails on the test modules: ghcide compiled with GHC 8.10 failed to load packages: ..., while continuing to work on the library modules.
After running stack build --test, running stack build recompiles. There are some differences in dependencies between the library, executable and the tests.

GHC 8.10 is quite old. What versions of GHC, HLS, and Stack are you using? Maybe try updating them. Also, it is not clear to me how exactly the error occurs. You say you run stack build --tests, but then the error message mentions ghcide, which is a part of HLS and not Stack. So ghcide shouldn't be involved if you just run stack build --tests manually. Also, is it --tests or --test?

edited the question to clarify

The combination of HLS and Stack seems to have known issues with multiple components (like test suites): https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#problems-with-multi-component-support-using-stack
